# java message routing based on payload property

Tags: java, spring, routes, java-8, spring-integration

I have an object that is currently being sent to one service to send the object to FTP.
I will get a different object that should be sent to MQ.
The type of object can be differentiated based on a property called format in the object. FTP/MQ.

A simple if condition would suffice to send the object to different services ( FTP/MQ service which do their thing ).

But, wondering if that is the right approach or should I use spring routing mechanism? To do that I have to create a new Message with payload as the object that I need to use and probably override the route(Message message) and do some stuff, still figuring out how to use that.

Could you suggest what is a good approach to use in my case or if there is anything better?

Answer (score 2):

Use a SI router, it should be very simple using SpEL expressions. Based only on the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#router-namespace) and without testing the below suggestion, here's my approach:

```
<int:router input-channel="inChannel" expression="payload.format">
    <int:mapping value="FTP" channel="ftpChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="MQ" channel="mqChannel"/>
</int:router>
```

where payload is your object.